# Unable To Find the application.properties file from out Side the War file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In the process of externalizing the application.properties file out side war. When I am creating a war file through jenkins showing error.

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-11-28 18:06:07.900
>   ERROR 22612 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
>   no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:   If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or
>   Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database settings
>   to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no
>   profiles are currently active).
>
> 2019-11-28 18:06:07.909 ERROR 22612 --- [           main]
>   o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while
>   allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@233795b6]
>   to prepare test instance
>   [com.assessmentAggregator.api.AssessmentAggregatorApiApplicationTests@74024f3]
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>   [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>   [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>   [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at

For Externalizing the properties file I used this code.

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder
            .properties("spring.config.name:" + AppConstants.Config.APPLICATION_PROPERTY_NAME,
                    "spring.config.location:" + AppConstants.Config.APPLICATION_PROPERTY_SOURCE_PATH)
            .sources(AssessmentAggregatorApiApplication.class);
}
```

and the value of 
      `AppConstants.Config.APPLICATION_PROPERTY_NAME=   String APPLICATION_PROPERTY_NAME = "foxmatrixapp.properties";

      AppConstants.Config.APPLICATION_PROPERTY_SOURCE_PATH=String APPLICATION_PROPERTY_SOURCE_PATH = "file:////mnt/assessment_aggregator/data/pdf/";`
and added this code in `pom.xml` file for excluding `application.properties` file from war file i used.

```
 <resources>
     <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource> 
   </resources>
```

Comment: And are those properties in said property file? Also this is a test that is failing, meaning it cannot load properties. The test will not use the `configure` method and thus doesn't know anything about those properties (nor I think it should).

Answer (score 0):

You may use another property source and point that placed at your destination folder.

For Example

```
@PropertySources({@PropertySource(value="file:somefolder/conf/bootstrap.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true), 
    @PropertySource(value="file:conf/bootstrap.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)})
```

At server file kept in **somefolder/conf** then load properties define in file.

```
@Value("${datasource.url}")
private String url;

@Value("${datasource.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${datasource.password}")
private String password;
```

Once loaded, it can be used anywhere.

***ignoreResourceNotFound=true*** been placed for reason in case property not found in then exception will not occur, It is all scenario based. You may change back to false

Comment: Those are loaded too late in the proces.

Comment: @M.Deinum How about load at Configuration?